# Configuring Nginx to display web page

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web, server, devops

I'm trying for the first time to configure nginx by following the instructions.

Someone in comments said that after:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_domain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

I should run this command:

```
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Could someone please explain, what the second command exactly do and why I need to run that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

that command is to remove the default nginx server block and you don't need to run it if you are fine with having default nginx server block. On server you will still be able to see file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default but it will not be active.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to create a new configuration file then this command is needed, but if you want to use and edit the default configuration file then there is no need to unlink it.

Answer (score 0):

The unlink command deletes a given file. Unlike rm, unlink accepts only a single argument.

To delete a symbolic link, run the unlink command followed by the symlink name.